# How to get an index of the element(element in field) in JSF?

Tags: jsf

Please help me. I want to make a link each element of the array in jsf.

```
<c:forEach items="#{lastRegionCallsReport.categoryCallsFromRegions}" end="#{lastRegionCallsReport.categCount-1}" var="categ" >
    <tr class="dr-table-row rich-table-row">
        <td style="padding-left: #{categ[1]}px" align="left">#{categ[0]}</td>
        <c:forEach items="#{categ}" var="oper" begin="2" end="21" >
            <td align="center">
                <a href="/aqpar/reports/applicationListCategory.seam?region=#{lastRegionCallsReport.regionsEng[5]}&amp;category=#{categ[22]}&amp;beginDate=#{operatorStatisticsReportManagerCategory.formatedBeginDate()}&amp;endDate=#{operatorStatisticsReportManagerCategory.formatedEndDate()}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{oper}"/>
                </a>
            </td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I need to get an indexes of the each oper element

Comment: please post your xhtml/jsp code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `varStatus` attribute of `c:forEach` to obtain the current loop index